# Is $B$ open in $A = [0,2] \subset \Bbb R$ or $\Bbb R$? Explanation of open/closed sets

Tags: general-topology

The point of this is me not understanding how exactly one proves that a set/subset is open, closed, or neither.

Say I have $A = [0,2] \subset \Bbb R$ where $A$ has the subspace topology given by $\Bbb R$ with the standard toplogy.

$B = (1,2]$ is neither open nor closed in $\Bbb R$, I think. This is is a guess based on its complement.

$B = (1,2]$ has a complement $[0,1]$ in $A$, so it would be open? But it has the same form as something that is neither in $\Bbb R$ if my thoughts are correct above.

Say I have $C = (0,2] \subset \Bbb R$ where $A$ has the subspace topology given by $\Bbb R$ with the lower limit toplogy.

$D = [1,2]$ is clearly closed in $\Bbb R$ notationally. It has square brackets. How would one prove that closedness besides pointing out the open complement? Is that possible?

I think the same applies for $C$ being closed in $D$, but again using the complement.

I am clearly missing a proof technique or idea.

Comment: You should start by clarifying the first point you find confusing. You say you're only guessing that $B=(1,2]$ is neither open nor closed in $\mathbb{R}$. This is true, but can you prove it?

Comment: To show a subset in a subspace is open, find an open subset $X$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $B = A \cap X$. To show that a subset in a subspace is closed, do the same above except for the relative complement $B^c$ inside $A$.  One of the above should be quite straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, $(1,2]$ *is* open on $[0,2]$, since $(1,2]=[0,2]\cap(1,\infty)$ and $(1,\infty)$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$.

You can also say that the complement of $(1,2]$ in$[0,2]$ is $[0,1]$, which is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$, and therefore a closed subset of $[0,2]$.

On the other hand, if you consider in $\Bbb R$ the lower limit topology and on $(0,2]$ the subspace topology, then $[1,2]$ is a closed subset of $(0,2]$ since it is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$ (again, with respect to the lower limit topology).